# Issue with receiving emails via Dovecot/Postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to set up roundcube on my server which seems to be working fine. I have gone through all of the steps and it allows me to send outgoing emails perfectly fine (tested that with yahoo), emails always go through. For some reason, however, if I reply to an email from yahoo to the mail server it sends back an error 550 (Recipient not found). I've looked everywhere for an answer but haven't found any. Has anyone else ran into this issue and found a fix?

If I need to give more information please let me know and I will do so.

Mail Log: (shortened)

```
Aug 14 16:35:03 pocketbukkit dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23142, secured
Aug 14 16:35:03 pocketbukkit dovecot: imap(philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=50/404
```

Failure Notice:

```
Sorry, we were unable to deliver your message to the following address.

<philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net>:
Remote host said: 550 5.1.1 <philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net> Recipient not found.  <http://x.co/irbounce> [RCPT_TO]

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

Received: from [66.196.81.174] by nm14.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 14 Aug 2014 17:32:15 -0000
Received: from [98.139.212.241] by tm20.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 14 Aug 2014 17:32:15 -0000
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1050.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 14 Aug 2014 17:32:15 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 688407.16699.bm@omp1050.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
Received: (qmail 48585 invoked by uid 60001); 14 Aug 2014 17:32:15 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s1024; t=1408037535; bh=x0RlACzX5sVtytN6BXeDvMLGd1pVEFkT/0DVPpu/nj0=; h=Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=k878XbIeHwBebjTlCtTMIDiq4jConh3s2/9XiC/WMt+6p3MqR2F9T5NY637MwcgeqCjzq5zaE4/Szd6Dw+bTgq2cxp7C5zYyAeJLLV6Xpia0ifHNG++5/dnLRsx/Bc+ZDzTRfT3D+c8Qi7anHX8EXDCHbnbCyn05LUfW0merG0Y=
X-YMail-OSG: HqtcMi8VM1kCguInS81hMn_yugn8daDV_XhSowgngtbDUoI
8BDAeFJvVoQ6b2YLS4oY2PF1Y_CTptPsGqWp3MTq5hAQqV.I4YHFih0wVJgx
T3IS58COMGhmNpzH1mX3SUlDz3K9k9g3C0cPcWrf7EA1DxAWZ72noqKf_wcw
sO96DikfIvWmuKeMHy_5A5613hfngbMWHoRj_6rM4AaSvl5yZk5SjdQHsIiA
atFeWbfiL6gjGtju5UyS_LZH0.pNWprVcGEkscX1EUc13S3n6oVyTNjO0dQR
k6tFBZX_eN6EGzULHNIpQP7etGLnmEMp.HL9UGKMU3vOYaAvQfhbLE.PyxuA
QLNoW9CsgrkEZm9f7_TY5YLD4fWyzfOs8tkubV.v2xqMYFy3_7.he8UzeOXG
p4NIycxTaP6A9eq8OKqhw8J0yDeYzjJb93G6u5zVbX27SvZlqrElx6lFRvuG
fqIiRLhOBdTwwgd_SIwjj6PdK0AQAb5.GhSDite8N57xVXk2JJBX3tIja14R
jkw9ytwdBb3gjgIhf_FJy_bqcDEdsByNIdg--
Received: from [71.65.70.90] by web140902.mail.bf1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Thu, 14 Aug 2014 10:32:15 PDT
X-Rocket-MIMEInfo: 002.001,VGVzdGluZyBpZiB0aGUgbWFpbCBzZXJ2ZXIgd29ya3MgY29ycmVjdGx5LgEwAQEBAQ--
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.201.700
Message-ID: <1408037535.80225.YahooMailNeo@web140902.mail.bf1.yahoo.com>
Date: Thu, 14 Aug 2014 10:32:15 -0700
From: Comedy Man <comedyman937@yahoo.com>
Reply-To: Comedy Man <comedyman937@yahoo.com>
Subject: Checking mail server
To: "philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net" <philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="-18013450-1588383846-1408037535=:80225"

---18013450-1588383846-1408037535=:80225
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Testing if the mail server works correctly.
---18013450-1588383846-1408037535=:80225
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<html><body><div style="color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;font-size:12pt"><div>Testing if the mail server works correctly.</div></div></body></html>
---18013450-1588383846-1408037535=:80225--
```

Postfix main.cf:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = $alias_maps

inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES

relay_domains = *
virtual_alias_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains=hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_minimum_uid = 2222
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:2222
virtual_gid_maps = static:2222

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

`/etc/postfix/vmail_aliases`:

```
support@pocketbukkit.net support@pocketbukkit.net
philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net
```

vmail_mailbox:

```
support@pocketbukkit.net           pocketbukkit.net/support
philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net    pocketbukkit.net/philipshilling
```

vmail_domains:

```
pocketbukkit.net            OK
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message, as also a complete snippet from your mailserver logs (`/var/log/mail.log`). Also post your postfix-Configuration `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Comment: @sebix Added them :)

Comment: @Domedyman937 The log is useless, we need a snippet for postfix, for the SMTP-part (that's for sending mails between servers), not IMAP (that's for checking your mailbox). What is `relay_domains = *` for?

Comment: Im not sure... I just went through a tutorial on how to set it up ( http://www.rosehosting.com/blog/mailserver-with-virtual-users-and-domains-using-postfix-and-dovecot-on-a-centos-6-vps/ )

Comment: Whats in your `/etc/postfix/vmail_aliases` and where's a complete `mail.log`, as requested before?

Comment: Aliases:
support@pocketbukkit.net           support@pocketbukkit.net
philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net    philipshilling@pocketbukkit.net

And there is no mail.log in /var/log/

Comment: log: Where is the snippet which you postet in your question from, if there's no `mail.log`? What's in your `/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox` and -`_domain`. Please you some effort on solving the problem, otherwise nobody is willing to help you.

Comment: The snippet that I posted is in /var/postfix/maillog (there is no dot) Added vmail_mailbox and domains to main post

Comment: The post `/var/postfix/maillog` containing the 550 plus all additional lines, that belong to the connection.

Comment: The entire file located at /var/log/maillog is at http://pastebin.com/b2xyfpzk

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's necessary to add aliases from your virtual mailboxes to themselves, and in fact this might be preventing mailbox lookup.  Also, since you're using `hash:` to specify the virtual mailboxes (and domains), you need to use postalias or postmap to create the hashmap versions of the files (the files actually used end in `.db` in this case and are BDB databases).

I believe you can also simply remove the `hash:` since your files are tiny and you probably don't need hashing for performance reasons for that.

Comment: Can you give me an example as to what Ill need to do in the config?  Im new to setting up this kind of thing...